# ColdFusion - Collection loop in cfscript

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfml

I have some tag based syntax that works in Railo.

```
<cfloop collection="#myArray#" item="j" index="i"></cfloop>
```

The above allows me to access the index 'i' and the item itself, 'j'.

I want to do the same in cfscript, so I used:

```
for ( i in myArray) {}
```

However, 'i' gives me the **item**...how can I access the **index** value?

As a work-around, I have had to manually count an index like so:

```
j = 1;
for ( i in myArray) {
j++;
}
```

But this feels dirty. Does the for in syntax of cfscript allow for a true alternative to cfloop's collection?

I have tried Google searching all of this but never get any decent result. Is there a way to rewrite my for in loop to allow me access to the index too?

Thanks,
Mikey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible *in ColdFusion*, I'm afraid, other than the work-around you are currently using, or just using an indexed for loop.

However in Railo, there is this (rather awful tag/script hybrid syntax):

```
<cfscript>
    loop array=[5,4,3,2,1] index="i" item="v"  {
        writeOutput("[#i#][#v#]<br>");
    }   
</cfscript>
```

So basically it's the `<cfloop>` without the angle brackets.

Comment: That's a real shame! I was hoping there would be an elegant way of doing it in this syntax, but my suspicions were correct it seems. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: NP. BTW, that CFLOOP syntax you're using is *Railo only*. It is *not* valid in CF. You might wanna update your text.

Comment: There in lies my problem. I think Railo implemented (a rather nice) way of doing this with tags, but felt the need to comply with ACF in their script version. Bummer! I have also edit my post to correct my false statement.

Answer (score 1):

In CF 10 and Railo 4, you could use the [Underscore.cfc library](http://russplaysguitar.github.io/UnderscoreCF/#each).

```
_ = new Underscore();// instantiate the library

_.each(myArray, function(item, index) {
   // code here
});
```

Although personally, I'd rather use one of the other functional methods, such a `map` or `reduce`, depending on what you're trying to do.

Note: I wrote Underscore.cfc

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<cfscript>
    for (key in struct) {
        writeOutput("#key# = #struct[key]# <br>");
    }
</cfscript>
```

or

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop collection="#params#" item="key" >
        #key# = #params[key]#         
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Remember to set "this.serialization.preservecaseforstructkey = true" in the Applicacion.cfc